# Spring Boot + Spring Rabbit MQ : Connecting over https secure layer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I can able to connect with RabbitMQ through http layer with the below properties and need help to connect with https url,

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost spring.rabbitmq.port=5672 
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
```

Below is the example of the target link which i want to connect.`enter code here`

Target URL: https://my.example.com/RabbitMQueue

Please share me any examples for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Port 5672 is amqp protocol not http; 15672 is (usually) secure amqp and you have to set `spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled=true`.

Comment: I tried with the following and I am not able to connect, spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.host=my.example.com/RabbitMQueue. When i see the logs it showing as "Attempting to connect to: my.example.com/RabbitMQueue:15672]"

Comment: It has to be enabled on the broker [documentation here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html).